# Postfix: Handle different sender

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I have currently the following Setup:

**Incoming E-Mails:**

- Customer A -> Mailserver of Customer A
- All other Customers -> Default Relay

For **Outgoing E-Mails**, I set up the `sender_dependent_relayhost` file

- @customer_a.tld -> relayhost A

And for everything else I set the default relayhost.

**My Problem is the following**:

The mails that go to customer A are redirected for some workers to their private E-Mail adress.

So the sender adress of the redirected E-Mails stay the same (so the sender is not @customer_a.tld) but something else.

My server now doesn't relay the e-Mails to Relayhost A but to the default Relayhost which won't handle sender domains it doesn't know.

**How can I tell postfix to redirect E-Mails dependent on the network IP, the E-Mails come from? So I could say "relay all E-Mails from [Customer A IP] to Relayhost A.**

I hope you understand my problem and somebody can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell postfix to redirect E-Mails dependent on the network IP, the E-Mails come from? So I could say "relay all E-Mails from [Customer A IP] to Relayhost A.

You can use [postfix access maps](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) and apply **FILTER** action to specific client. For example Costumer A has IP 192.168.1.168, then add this to smtpd_*_restriction (for example: smtpd_client_restriction)

In `main.cf`

```
smtpd_client_restriction = 
                  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/customerA-relayhost
                  ... other restriction ...
```

In `/etc/postfix/customerA-relayhost`, add the line

```
192.168.1.168  FILTER smtp:[relayhost A]
```

Run [postmap](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html) /etc/postfix/customerA-relayhost and don't forget to execute `postfix reload`.

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible, to set a default external relayhost in postfix and set the CustomerA FILTER to ignore this default relayhost and use the local relay instead?

Comment: Yep, your scenario will works